# Using JavaScript Math.pow for Excel formula

Tags: javascript

In Excel I have this equation:

```
=(P12/P10)^(1/P13)-1
```

I would have thought this equates to:

```
Math.pow( ( P12 / P10 ), (1 / P13 ) ) - 1
```

I appear to be wrong.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with precedence I would say but don't know how Excel works. Can you post your numbers and your output in Excel and JS?

Comment: what wrong ? 

`var P12=6,P10=2,P13=0.5;Math.pow((P12/P10),(1/P13))-1==8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official order of operations for Excel from [Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/25189) seems to agree that those two should be equivalent.

In Excel I test with 27 in P12, 3 in P10 and 2 in P13, the formula evaluates to 2

In javascript I test Math.pow((27/3),(1/2))-1 which also evaluates to 2

Comment: XLS: P12 = 373,239
 , P10 = 200,000
 , P13 = 8.5
 , Answer = 0.076186448
In JS: Answer = 0

Comment: Ah, sorted. Being a % I'd omitted to multiple 100 and then subtract 100 to get 0.1762 up to 7.62%. Thanks for the help on this one. Carry on!

Answer (score 1):

Should work according to *[this](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformulas/ss/formula_begin_5.htm)*.

Are you missing something?

Comment: Thanks Vandesh. All sorted.